# When deploying website handheld shows desktop version instead of mobile version

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile, dns

I've developed a website using MVC4 in visual studio. The standard template includes code for displaying correctly in mobile browsers.
When I run the project, it applies all of the mobile css. Also, when I deployed the website to my own (amateur) IIS server, it applies the mobile css perfect.

Then I bought a DNS address, and forwarded it to my server. Now when I visit the DNS address, it shows the desktop version instead of the mobile version.

What is breaking it down? How can I fix this?

Thanks for your time to answer my question.

EDIT

Thanks for your input. I only have one CSS file with a media section. On some browsers it displays correctly and on others it doesnt. But the problem only exists when visiting the DNS, not when visiting the direct ip-address.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  tag. Put all stylings for any browser that doesn't support javascript intp the  tag. That way since most moblie browser do not support javescript You can put all stylings of mobile view into that tag and all would work well...... GOODLUCK!!! @da_skywalker10

Answer (score 0):

If:

- You have access to the HTML page and can edit it.
- You have 2 different CSS files (one for **mobile** layout and one for
  **desktop** layout).

I would suggest checking if the head tag of the HTML contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="locationOfCssFile.css" media="all">
```

Note: The above line will display the webpage according to one CSS file whether it's viewed on a mobile device or a desktop screen.

If it does, then change `media="all"` so you would have **2 link tags**, one for **desktop** and one for **mobile**.

It would look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="locationOfDesktopCssFile.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="locationOfMobileCssFile.css" media="handheld">
```

Source:
[HTML link media Attribute - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp)

Comment: I only have 1 css file, with a media section within. The problem only exists when visiting the site through the DNS-address, but not with the direct IP-address of my modem. Also I noticed a few other slight differences in CSS, like a padding at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @user3153169 I strongly advice duplicating your CSS file so you would have one for each "view". That would result in more control over the website and easier management of different elements' style for different views. After you have the 2 CSS files, go ahead and edit the "handheld" one. So to fix your padding issue you would need to add/modify the body tag such `body{padding-bottom:-10px;}`, decrease or increase the number until you're satisfied with the result.